# libxml2 in C++, how to set encoding

Tags: c++, libxml2

I am creating a xml document using libxml2 in C++. After xml file is created, i am seeing the following line in the top of the xml buffer.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

I have not specified any encoding while creating the doc. Some of the xml content  ascii value is greater than 127 which is not handled by ISO-8859-1 encoding. For e.g: I have pound character **(£)** in my xml content. So whenever it encounters ascii value greater than 127 it breaks and my xml file is incomplete. I read from some forums saying that changing the encoding to UTF-8 will handle this kind of scenarios. But I don't know how to specify encoding for the xml doc creation. Following is the sample code I have used.

```
xmlDoc *doc = NULL;
xmlChar *xmlbuff = NULL;
int buffersize;
xmlNodePtr pNode;
doc = xmlNewDoc(NULL);
pNode = xmlNewNode(0, (const xmlChar*)"Temp");
xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, pNode);
xmlSetProp(pNode, (const xmlChar*)"Item", (const xmlChar*)"Office£");
xmlDocDumpMemory(doc, &xmlbuff, &buffersize);
xmlFree(xmlbuff);
xmlFreeDoc(doc);
doc = NULL;
```

**output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Temp Item="Office
```

Comment: Hint: the observed behaviour was triggered by your call to xmlSetProp. How do you think the value of "Item" was interpreted ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you should use `xmlDocDumpMemoryEnc()` (or `xmlDocDumpFormatMemoryEnc()`, if you want control the indentation too) instead `xmlDocDumpMemory()`.

Something like

```
xmlDocDumpMemoryEnc(doc, &xmlbuff, &buffersize, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: How about saving? Is there any libxml2 api to save with encoding?

Comment: @impulse - try with `xmlSaveFileEnc()` or `xmlSaveFormatFileEnc()`